# 雨粉 pronunciation and meaning

Tags: words

I was reading the transcript of Bilingual News and came across the word 雨粉 in a discussion about Mars.

None of the internet dictionaries I checked had this word. Google thought I was searching a Chinese word.

What is the reading - amegona? Something else?

I assume it means raindrop.

Edit: Perhaps I copied the word wrongly and it's actually ametsuba.

Comment: So it says 「粉」 and not「粒」?

Comment: Probably my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

雨粉 must be a typo of **雨粒｛あまつぶ｝** a *raindrop* or like that.

雨粒 is read *ama-tsubu*, neither *ame-tsubu* nor *ame-tsuba*.